# Authentication Interceptor not working in angular 6

Tags: angular, adal.js

I am trying to implement Azure B2C into my Angular 6 App:

authentication-interceptor.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private adalService: AdalService) { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next:HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>{
        const authHeader = this.adalService.userInfo.token;
        var header = 'Bearer ' + authHeader;
        const authReq = req.clone({headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', header)});
        return next.handle(authReq);
    }
}
```

api-service.ts:

```
getMenuItemsDistinct():Observable<string[]>{
   var url = `${environment.apiUrl}/api/menuitemsdistinct`;
   return  this.httpClient.get<string[]>(url);    
}
```

module.ts:

```
 providers: [
    AdalService, 
      AuthenticationGuard,
      { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthenticationInterceptor, multi: true }
]
```

Fiddler:
[image]

I would expect that the request in fiddler would show a bearer token (I am not sure)?. The strange part is when I debug the app, a breakpoint is hit in the AuthenticationInterceptor intercept method, but as you can see in fiddler i dont see the token, and I get an 401 afterwards. Any suggestions how to troubleshoot this, or maybe I am missing some steps here? I have a fine token in the code when debugging.

As hugo states the google crome tools shows the bearer. Not sure why fiddler dosent:

[image]

Comment: Any errors in the console while debugging?

Comment: Did you try checking the request headers on chrome dev tools? Just trying to rule out possible false positives.

Comment: Only 401 error. If i remove Authorize attr everything works as expected. I will look in crome dev tools.

Comment: Try putting a console.log() in intercept() method to see if it does work.

Comment: I get into the intercept method, it seems like @HugoNoro is right. Fiddler dosents catch the bearer på google crome tools does. The error is something completely else. I attached image in main post. Hugo can you post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you might just be having a problem with fiddler or fiddler configurations. Please try and check the same request headers on chrome dev tools. There is nothing wrong in the way the request is being built. It’s according to the documentation.

You might also be having an issue with the headers being returned from the server on the initial `OPTIONS` request which would translate in having issue to perform the actual request. It might be a mismatch in your CORS configuration.

From the added screenshot the error `audience is invalid` usually means you might be trying to access a resource you’re not supposed to. Probably some azure config or data access rules.

Comment: Whats really strange is I am redirected to the loginpage. Successfully I write my user name and password, and gets a token. But when I following call the API in the same domain, then I get the 401 invalid token. Kind of strange when it is in the same app and domain.

Comment: Daymn it was something as stupid of API pointing to another app than the web. Thanks all for your help, highly appreciated.

Comment: Always glad to help and it’s great it solved your problem :)